# How do I group rows in a table by one column's value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of data (5000+ rows) with two columns, ID and value.

It may look like this:

```
ID Value
01 02
01 03
01 17
02 05
03 06
03 28
```

What I want to do is find the average value for each ID. i.e. =AVERAGE(rows where id=1)

How can I go about this?

Comment: You have answers here, but if your result seem to not come out, make sure your values with leading zeroes are not considered text.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2007 and beyond use [AVERAGEIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx)

Example:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A7,1,B2:B7)
```

Will return the average of the values in `B2:B7` where the corresponding value in `A2:A7` is `1`.

Comment: That works great for average. Figured it out for 'maxif'
    =MAX(IF($B$2:$B$4988=G1,$C$2:$C$4988))

Answer (score 1):

And, if you need the averages for all the ID values (not just "01"), use a pivot table and summarize by the "average":

[image]